# Recycler view onClick produces another Recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I am trying to start a new Recycler view upon clicking a container view from another recycler view. Essentially I have list of NBA teams presented as a recycler view in "NBA_Adapter"; when each team is clicked it will bring the user to another recycler view showing the players in the team. I am trying to do this using two classes that extend recycler view. The issue is that I am unable to start the second class, which I suspect is because the second class does not extend "AppCompatActivity" and instead extends RecyclerView, which the manifest file is asking me to do since it does not recognize my second class.
Manifest below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nba">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Second_Adapter">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

         </intent-filter>
</activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Main Activity below:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //instantiates the parameters
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        
        adapter = new NBA_Adapter(getApplicationContext());
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

  
}
```

Part of 1st Class below:

```
 @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TEAMS current = (TEAMS) containerView.getTag();

                    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Second_Adapter.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", current.getId());

                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
```

My second class is essentially the same as my first class. The only reason I do not use the same recycler view is that I am having a hard time implementing it as I am also using a search view for each recycler view. So at the moment I am separating them. Any hints or links are appreciated showing how I can do this is appreciated.